# Can ActiveRecord call native db functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Is there anyway to use native database functions in ActiveRecord?

Example: Suppose I want to use now() in Postgres. I don't want to use Time.now because I want the database time to be used, not the Rails server time.

Something like this, which obviously doesn't work.

```
TableCommon.new( {:upd_date => now()} )
```

Note: This is a ***contrived*** example. I don't want to use now(), but I want to use other database functions, and wish to know how to use it via ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access it directly via the connection

```
TableCommon.new( :upd_date => TableCommon.connection.select_value("now()") )
```

connection.select_value to get a single result back, ignoring the rest:

```
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value("select 1,2")  #returns 1
```

connection.select to get a hash back:

```
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select("select 1 as a ,2 as b")  #{"a"=>1, "b" =>2}
```

connection.select_all will give an array of hashes, one per row like select.

connection.select_values will give an array, with the value from the first value in each row.  It's like select_value but with multiple rows.

Comment: This would make a db call to get now(), right? Is there anyway to do it without making the db call?

Comment: It would, otherwise the value wouldn't be available to your model.   It's also going to get quoted when the insertion happens.  Unless you want to rewrite how rails handles insertions,   I would suggest an after_create callback that does something like TableCommon.update_all("dyn_column = now()", :id => self.id)